# Ubuntu + Apache doesn't work on port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have some problems with apache (OS Ubuntu). for some reasons apache doesn't work on port 80.

For this settings:
etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

etc/apache2/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuiXE.jpg).
I try to connect "my_server_ip" or "my_server_ip:80" browser say "connection closed"

If i change  port to 8080(for example) and  try to connect "my_server_ip:8080" it's work fine and i see default apache page.

settings:
etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

etc/apache2/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    </VirtualHost>
```

[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oicx7.jpg).

Comment: what if you put your ip address instead of * in the VirtualHost ?

Comment: did you really started apache services ? any log in /var/log/apache2/error.log ? what is your apache configuration in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ? do you have another process on port 80 (check netstat) ?

Comment: by the way you need to start apache as root for port 80, port 8080 can be started without being root

Comment: What is th result of the ommand `Apache -S` ?

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem:

```
AllowOverride None
```

should be changed to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate where did you do such change?

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons in Debian GNU/Linux stretch I was able to issue a `systemctl start apache2` and seeing it running but not listening. The cause was: the package `apache2` was not installed. Really don't know how.

Fixed with:

```
apt install apache2
```